# Angular - reload or refresh object in child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a create case page of 2 types(say positive case and negative case)with a banner in the top, and below that I have a left panel and right panel as 2 DIV's.

So I created a page called -> caseTemplate.component.ts

Within case template based on which button is clicked I either go to positiveCase.component.ts or negativeCase.component.ts which is case creation and not edit.

So basically,
caseTemplate.component.html has an *ngIf which either directs to positiveCase.component.ts or negativeCase.component.ts

```
caseTemplate.component.html
////...
<div class="row" style="padding: 10px 0px;">    
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="height: 100px;"> 
        <positiveCase [selCase]="selCase" *ngIf="isPositive"></positiveCase>
        <negativeCase [selCase]="selCase" *ngIf="!isPositive"></negativeCase>
    </div>
</div>

....///
```

selCase is Cases object which has caseId is set to null, isNewCase is new , caseType set to positive/negative in caseTemplate.component.ts.
Below the button is a table of rows with already exisiting cases. When a row is clicked from this table control goes to same caseTemplate but the selCase is set to corresponding caseId, isNewCase as false, caseType as positive/negative.

positiveCase.component.html - > This has the banner and the left side div defined and rightDiv is child to positiveCase.component.html. Code looks like below,

```
    positiveCase.component.ts
////..........
export class positiveCase  implements OnInit {
    @Input() selCase : Cases; 
    
    onSubmit(){
        this.caseService.saveCase(this.createPositiveForm.value).subscribe( posts =>{
            this.data = posts;
            },
            error => {
              console.log('saveCase - error',error);
              this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:error.error, sticky: true});        
            },
            () => {
              this.caseObj = this.data;
              this.selCase.caseId = this.caseObj.caseId;
        });
    }
.............////////

positiveCase.component.html 
///............
<div class="row recHeader" *ngIf="showBanner">
    <div style="padding:3px;" class="col-sm-4" >{{caseObj.id}}</div>
    <div style="padding:3px;" class="col-sm-4" >{{caseObj.firstName}} {{caseObj.middleInitial}} {{caseObj.lastName}}</div>
    <div style="padding:3px;" class="col-sm-4" >Case Status : {{bannerCaseStatus}}</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 10px 0px;">    
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100px;"> ..............
    .................
    .................
    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
        <div align="center">
            <button pButton icon="pi" type="button" label="Submit" (click)="onSubmit()"  [disabled]="!createPositiveForm.valid"></button>&nbsp;
            <button pButton icon="pi" type="button" label="Close"  (click)="onClose()" ></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
        <caseAssign [selCase]="selCase"></caseAssign>
    </div>
</div>
    
....///////////
```

caseAssign.component.ts has the @Input() selCase : Cases; as the input element.

*This is my scenario where i would want to pass the updated selCase to caseAssign.component.ts.*

Say i clicked positive button initially(which is a new positive case creation), controls goes to caseTemplate.component.ts and sets all the selCase object(caseId is set to null, isNewCase is new , caseType set to positive).
At this point the caseId is null since its a new case. selCase in positiveCase.component.html/ts  and caseAssign.component.ts/html is null.

Once a case is created and clicked on save, I change the selCase to selCase.caseId with a new value. I want to pass this new selCase/caseId to caseAssign page too.

I tried to do using ngOnChanges(), in caseAssign.component.ts but its not getting triggered. What can I do to refresh the selCase object values once the object in the parent page change. I tried ngOnChanges() in positiveCase.component.ts and caseAssign.component.ts, but its called only when the page loads and not when the save in parent is clicked. Any suggestions please.

Below is the ngOnChanges() used in caseAssign.component.ts

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log("O N C H A N G E E V E N T......" , changes);
    console.log('selCase + ', this.selCase);
    for ( const propName in changes){
        let change = changes[propName];
        console.log("propName",propName);
        console.log('change - ',change);
        if ( propName == 'selCase' ){
            console.log('HERE....');
        } 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: add the code where you're updating `selCase`

Comment: @Ramesh Reddy I have updated the postiveCase.component.html with onSubmit() method which updates selCase and also updated the html to show submit button

Comment: the issue might be because of mutating the state, do you only want to update the id?

Comment: Right I want to just update the id, so caseAssign can be done with that id.

Comment: try `this.selCase = { ...this.selCase, caseId: this.caseObj.caseId,}`

Comment: I updated your line of code in the onSubmit(). The value did not change and the ngOnChanges() is not called.

Comment: hmm, try adding a `console.log` after that line and check if the object is updated properly

Comment: SelCase is updated as per console logs. caseId is no longer null and has a value. However ngOnChanges() isnt being called in caseAssign.component.ts.

Comment: I see the issue now, you're passing `selCase` all the way from the parent. So when you want to update `selCase`, you should try to update the one that is present in the parent component. To simplify this, move the `selCase` state to a service.

Comment: So you mean to say change it in caseTemplate.component.ts is it? But that is not possible.What do you mean by putting them in service? can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Yes, you can either use [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) or a [service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)